# Pygame 'LEFT' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, mouseevent, pygame

I'm working on a game. I have pygame imported. 
I am using Python 3.3 and Pygame 3.3.
The same error message all the time "LEFT" is not defined.
I did exact copies of what were on the internet as I already did a search for the problem.
Here is my code. I have tried a few different ways and neither seem to work.

method 1:

```
import pygame
event = pygame.event.poll()
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == LEFT:
    ....command
```

method 2: (basically going all in)

```
from pygame import *
from pygame.locals import *
import pygame
event = pygame.event.poll()
if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == LEFT:
    ......command
```

Before telling me, on both those methods I tried switching between "LEFT" and "pygame.LEFT", and so on.

Any ideas?

Hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define `LEFT` yourself:

```
LEFT = 1
```

The [Pygame tutorial](http://lorenzod8n.wordpress.com/2007/05/30/pygame-tutorial-3-mouse-events/) I think you are following does exactly that. In other words, the `pygame` library has no constants for this value, it's just an integer.

Comment: Thanks a million, worked a charm. In my Program (maybe it's new with Pygame 3.3) I had to define RIGHT as 3, and LEFT as 1. But not a big deal thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: +1 There is no predefined constant for the mouse buttons. 1 = Left, 2 = Middle, 3 = Right, 4+5 are the mouse wheel.

Answer (score 1):

As *Martijn Pieters* [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14874061/1114687), the `pygame` library has no constants for the possible values of `event.button`.

Here's <sup><sub>what I think is</sub></sup> a complete list of the possible values (as a class, so it won't clutter your global namespace):

```
class MouseButtons:
    LEFT = 1
    MIDDLE = 2
    RIGHT = 3
    WHEEL_UP = 4
    WHEEL_DOWN = 5
```